# Unwanted list changing through functioncall

Tags: python, list, function

The general project is to re-build an enigma machine. However, the problem is this:
I have a list and I want to rearrange it in a way that the first element is appended to the same list and then the first element is deleted.

Basicly, I want this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

l_new = [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

for this purpose I constructed the function

```
def switch_up(list):
    list.append(list[0])
    del list[0]

    return list
```

The problem: When calling this function with a list, it does not only return the changed list, but changes the original list given as the argument.
The full code looks like this:

```
    def switch_up(list):
        list.append(list[0])
        del list[0]

        return list


    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    my_list2 = switch_up(my_list)

    print(my_list)
    print(my_list2)
```

My expected/desired output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
```

The output I get is:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Don’t name a variable `list`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are altering the list passed into the function. That isn't a copy of the list it's the *same* list. You should just make a copy and return it with something like:

```
def switch_up(l):
    # list slices will make shallow copy
    return l[1:] + l[:1]

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_list2 = switch_up(my_list)

print(my_list)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(my_list2)
# [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable in python and therefore it is assumed, that you want to do operations on the original list. If you do not want that you have to manually copy your list for example with `list.copy`. For more information on copy please see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

All you created is a "pointer" called `my_list2` to the same value as `my_list` if you would for example iclude `my_list2[1] = 'a'` the result would be:

```
my_list = [2, 'a', 4, 1]
my_list2 = [2, 'a', 4, 1]
```

And btw you should **never** name your variables the same as inbuilt functions, like `list`